# Statsmodels - Poisson GLM is taking more than an hour to fit the model - does not return anything

Tags: performance, time, statsmodels

I am trying to run a poisson GL regression with statsmodel on my training dataset (of 30.000 rows/observations) on Jupyter Notebook with the following code but it has been running for more than an hour and it does not return anything yet. I tried to shut it down and starting it again and I am running it on two different laptops (8 GB RAM one and 16 GB RAM the other) but nothing works...

Can somebody please give me some suggestions on how to fix it?

`code`

```
df=pd.read_csv('gravity.csv',sep=';')
```

```
mask = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8
df_train = df[mask]
df_test = df[~mask]
print('Training data set length='+str(len(df_train)))
print('Testing data set length='+str(len(df_test)))
```

```
expr = """BTI ~ GDP_mult + distwces + DAI_mult + year + contig + comlang_off + colony"""
```

```
y_train, X_train = dmatrices(expr, df_train, return_type='dataframe')
y_test, X_test = dmatrices(expr, df_test, return_type='dataframe')
```

```
poisson_training_results = sm.GLM(y_train, X_train, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
```

Comment: Do you have nans in your data? This should take at most a few seconds.  (In the old times some linear algebra, BLAS/LAPACK. got stuck with nans. But I think newer versions of those raise exceptions now.) Do you see any Runtime warnings that would indicate numerical problems.

Comment: Aside: applying dmatrices to train and test data separately, might not create consistent transformations if there are stateful transforms, e.g. categorical variables.